# Desktop Cube, Compiz, and GNOME. Bad Mix?

Tags: gnome, compiz

I've been using Compiz Fusion under the GNOME environment happily with 10.10 Maverick Meerkat, but when 11.04 Natty Narwhal came along, it started giving me problems with windows missing a title bar. I finally got the effects to work and the title bars back, at the cost of:

1. **Not being able to switch between workspaces on the Workspace Switcher**
2. **Undraggable windows, even with the Alt-drag method**

I checked online, and nothing seems to give me any relevant answer.
I asked around on #ubuntu on IRC, and a user suggests it might be a bug with the nVidia card. (I assume it would be the nVidia driver that I used with 10.10 with the Intel integrated graphics).

Anybody has any input on how to deal with this issue? I could bear with it (since I'm just using Metacity). If there is no absolute way, then my last resort would be to downgrade to 10.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's bad mix. Desktop Cube is not supported in Unity. But if you really want it, try this http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/compiz-cube-natty/